# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, inflate-exception

I am facing some problem when I click the back button and go back to the location fragment, I got an error below:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                                                                               at com.everstudio.nadejenew.LocationFragment.onCreateView(LocationFragment.java:73)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps(BackStackRecord.java:807)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2360)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:823)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:776)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:178)
>                                                                               at com.everstudio.nadejenew.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:110)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:408)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:187)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #14: Duplicate id 0x7f0f00c6, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3447)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:177)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                                                                               at com.everstudio.nadejenew.LocationFragment.onCreateView(LocationFragment.java:73) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps(BackStackRecord.java:807) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2360) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:823) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:776) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:178) 
>                                                                               at com.everstudio.nadejenew.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:110) 
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:408) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:187) 
>                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
>                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

I did checked many post and tried all solutions, but its not working. It seems that other menu item is not a problem, Only this location page gives an error.

fragment_location.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

LocationFragment.java

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);// this is the line 73
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: change the id of fragment. Its duplicating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove your mapFragment on onDestroyView in LocationFragment.java.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (mapFragment != null)
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason is this you use name instead of class,

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Try updating around this code base.

```
  FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   Fragment fragment = fmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment)fragment;
        GoogleMap supportMap = supportmapfragment.getMap()
```

You are using childSupportmanager , also this line `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);` you never anchored your map view from it, example view.findViewVyId you never did that

Comment: also name should be class,

Comment: class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Comment: u replaced name with class and renamed it back to map id

Comment: <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/> still error

Comment: what ? i do not comprehend